# Find intersection of 2 vector coordinate points?

Tags: python

I have 2 sets of data. First is (X,Y), second is (sX, sY). These 2 sets of data have a common intersecting point. I want to find the intersection point (can be multiple or single) of these 2 data sets and the (X,Y) coordinate and (sX, sY) coordinate to the left and right of the intersection point. Find below the attached data

```
sX      =   np.array([-20000, 0, 10000, 40000])
sY      =   np.array([400000,400000,370000, 320000])
#
X = np.array([ -42511.39120081,  -41162.03618773,  -39569.14753556,
        -35456.17500301,  -32679.740863  ,  -27909.4795152 ,
        -18043.90334475,  -16739.03515622,  -11966.40224792,
         -5457.43885436,   -1974.19548315,    1612.6087504 ,
          2067.30503084,    8643.06707226,   12837.72525583,
         15307.19705378,   17027.36753134,   17071.59864826,
         33936.11882314,   34278.79468656,   34476.61704745,
         38158.25661822,   39848.28959228,   41956.72582408,
         45164.50724157,   46230.92552002,   47886.68542507,
         49046.00122228,   49555.60159235,   50338.23870893,
         58882.11117872,   68733.94172537,   71774.82308826,
        110450.93324733,  111599.75183894,  112602.89111697,
        113881.7040512 ])

Y = np.array([ 228251.19825081,  230583.93531626,  233331.11161642,
        240441.01092232,  245240.56187394,  253478.75628186,
        270522.9733343 ,  272773.30832584,  281012.42774874,
        292229.25066418,  298245.2126661 ,  304438.214557  ,
        305237.34824933,  316868.11198967,  324286.15993646,
        328648.43365539,  331685.06094314,  331761.78491836,
        361574.37018552,  362178.34470217,  362863.66652499,
        375965.64871771,  381981.13511198,  389467.85830642,
        400870.84443964,  404675.99664723,  410549.82353843,
        414676.24431532,  415900.80400938,  416975.0460433 ,
        426163.12838202,  436755.58167939,  440008.96015215,
        481606.30492179,  481985.52601648,  481298.07692515,
        479284.44077501])

plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.plot(X,Y,'x')
plt.plot(sX, sY)
plt.plot(sX,sY,'o')
plt.show()
```

I have trouble figuring out the intersection point of these 2 line segments and also the corresponding coordinates to the left and right of the intersecting point. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You misuderstand the purpose of this site. In general, we fix problems with code here. Please ask a question about your code.

Comment: You never did attach an image. Are you asking for the intersection point of the two resulting *graphs* of your plots? If your graphs intersect at multiple points, which intersection do you want?

Comment: Hi @Rory, I edited my post accordingly. I made a mistake calling it a vector. `X` and `Y` are coordinate information and so is `sX` and `sY`. Yes I am asking for the intersecting point of the two resulting graphs of the plot. I would like to know all intersecting points.

Comment: Do an internet search for code on finding the intersection of two line segments--there are many such web pages. Then implement a scan: look at the x-coordinates of both data sets in increasing order and examine all pairs of line segments that have overlapping x-coordinates. Be aware that you may get infinitely many intersection points, which happens when line segments overlap. You really should have done the web search before asking your question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are looking for the intersecting points of the line segments generated by the points `(x,y)` from the sets `X * Y` and `Sx * Sy`, respectively.

The brute-force method would be to solve for each 2 pairs of points from your set whether they induce intersecting line segments. I doubt there is a more efficient method for such a general problem, but since your datasets are small computation time shouldn't be an issue.

#### Brute-force method:

The line segments between `(x1,y1)-(x2,y2)` and `(u1,v1)-(u2,v2)` have an intersecting point if for some `a,b` between 0 and 1 you can solve

```
a*x1 + (1-a)*x2 == b*u1 + (1-b)*u2
a*y1 + (1-a)*y2 == b*v1 + (1-b)*v2
```

So for each contiguous pair of points in your two datasets you can solve this equation and check whether a and b lie between 0 and 1. If that is the case, the lines will intersect.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Works perfectly :). But just out of curiosity, can I know what the `a` and `b` signify and how you derive the equations above?

Comment: A line segment connecting two points is a convex combination of the two points. The `a` (resp. `b`) signify how close you are on the line to the left (`a=0`) or the right(`a=1`) point, so to say. The equations state the fact that the x and y-coordinates must be the same on both line segments.